# Higher Order Functions in TensorFlow - How to use?

Tags: tensorflow

the new higher order functions within TF is detailed here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#map_fn

In particular, the map function looks useful. Here is what they wrote for the tutorial:

```
  elems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  squares = map_fn(lambda x: x * x, elems)
  # squares == [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
```

Thus I created an empty python file:

```
import tensorflow as tf
elems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
squares = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x * x, elems)
```

Running this gives this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.pyc in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape)
    323   else:
    324     if values is None:
--> 325       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
    326     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
    327     # provided if possible.

ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

Edit: I'm using TensorFlow version 0.8.

Comment: Thanks for asking about this! It turns out there are some bugs in `tf.map_fn()` and its friends, which mean that conversions to tensor aren't handled properly. I've opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2366) and have a fix in progress.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of anywhere where I might find an example of tf.map_fn() with a tensor as an input?

Comment: I think it's a fairly new addition to the library, so there aren't many examples around yet. The only one I could find was in [this unit test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f06280b0b8fd4bda35231124186ba3ff7a1f271b/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/functional_ops_test.py#L65).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems OK, but I was able to fix it using the `numpy array` something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

elems = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype="float32")
squares = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x * x, elems)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(squares)
```

This outputs:

```
[  1.   4.   9.  16.  25.  36.]
```